# Prevent browser from closing in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using asp.net 2.0 with c#.

i want a pop up to be displayed when user tries to close the browser and if user click on "no" [i.e. he don't want browser to be closed] then it prevent browser to get closed.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: That is not possible, and it would be a horribly rude thing to do if it were.

Comment: A few points 1/ it is possible (See various other answers below) 2/ It's not necessarily ruder than allowing the users to lose data without warning. 3/ This isn't necessarily an asp.net question, as it relates entirely to the browser and can apply just as easily to an application written using Java, PHP etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code they use is

```
window.onbeforeunload=function() {
  if (somereasonorother) return "You did not save your stuff"
}
```

Comment: PS: old but possibly still useful for you: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101304-1.aspx

Comment: You are welcome. Please note the other comments are valid too - if the user wants to leave they should be allowed to - and if your application is built on the need to know when they leave or close the browser, you may be in trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointy, this is entirely possible, and it's done by many web pages for perfectly reasonable reasons.

Try something like this:

```
function areYouSure() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
}
window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to attach yourself to the `onbeforeunload` event:

```
<body onbeforeunload="ConfirmClose();">
```

But I have to mention that it won't work on all browsers. The only ones that prompted something after I closed a window were Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer; Opera ignored the code in the JavaScript method.

This is mostly because some browsers trigger the `onbeforeunload` event only when you're trying to leave the current page by visiting another one, and not when you close the current window / tab.

Comment: It seems that I tried this one on an older version of Firefox; it works with the current Firefox release. I've now updated my answer; thanks for the hint