# before closing the Application browser should prompt conformation

Tags: asp.net

I have a small requirement..

if the user dint sign off or log off then he try's to close the browser IE clicking on 'X' (top right of IE or Firefox browser ) then i need to ask a conformation message like "Are you sure you want to close ?" ...
I am using Master page in my application and i tried the event : "window.onbeforeunload " in my master page its works fine, shows an alert(conformation) message. but if i press back button on the browser(IE on IE or Firefox) then also its firing(but it should not) is there any way to full fill my requirement ..I hope i had explained u clearly...if not pl z let me know........

what i mean to say is.. if the Session("USerid") is active or if it contains any value ie.
Session("USerid")="XXX"
at that moment if user trys to close the browse(click in 'X'/Close button browser either IE or Firefox ) it should give prompt a message "are u sure do u want to close?"..

Answer (score 1):

Its all about design steps - but the close and the back button is the same, the close the page, so maybe its impossible to have them all together.

To open, close your script you can make a simple trick. Place them inside a literal and open or close it.

```
<asp:literal run="server" id="txtCloseAlert">
<script>
    ... you code here ....
</script>
</asp:literal>
```

and on code behind.

```
txtCloseAlert.visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("USerid"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this recently and there does not appear to be a standard / consistent way to do this cross-browser hence you back-button problem.

On IE at least you get an event object passed as a parameter to the `onbeforeunload` method that you can use to get the mouse position, but in FireFox you don't and you would need some other way to determine whether a confirmation is required.  It is quite posible that you could get the mouse position in some other way as I haven't looked into that.  Point is that if your mouse is not on your form you probably want a confirmation.

You can look at this SO question:
[Prevent browser from closing in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290660/prevent-browser-from-closing-in-asp-net)

Or do an Internet search on 'onbeforeunload prevent browser closing'.

In your case a synchronous ajax call can be made to the server to do the test.

HTH